# How do I pass Information to another component using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, components, e-commerce

I have 2 classes: singlePageView.js and singlePageView.style.js
My problem: I do load product information (simple ecommerce site) from my DB but I still have problems displaying the images correctly.

the **singlePageView** class gets the Product information from my mongoDB with this API call:

```
  let url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/products/"+match.params.slug;      
  const { data, loading } = useDataApi(url);
```

The Data loads perfectly, but the Image rendered is always the same because it loads always the same content inside the **singlePageView.stlye.js** :

```
import singlePostBgImg from 'assets/images/single-post-bg.jpg';

export const PostImage = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${singlePostBgImg});
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    height: 406px;
  }
```

this is how postImage is rendered (inside singlePageView.js):

```
return (
    <SinglePageWrapper>
      <PostImage>
.
.
.
```

My question is as follows:
How can I pass the Link for images (which I get from my DB ) to the singlePageView.style.js class?

My thoughts are something like this: `<PostImage {*linktoimage*}>` and then, somehow, catch the link inside the style.js class.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
const { data, loading } = useDataApi(url);
return (
    <SinglePageWrapper>
      <PostImage image={data.img} />
```

---

```
import singlePostBgImg from 'assets/images/single-post-bg.jpg';

export const PostImage = styled.div`
  background-image: ${(props) => url(${props.image})};
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    height: 406px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people will argue this image is a part of the content, not just decoration, so it should not be css but html. So now, let's go back to your problem.

You can do it very simply by using style property in react:

```
<PostImage style={{backgroundImage: data.img}} />
```

Or as you want to do it, with styled div

```
const Component = () => {
   return <PostImage image={'https://...'} />
}

const PostImage = styled.div`
  background-image: ${props => url(${props.image})};
  ...
```

[Adapting based on props is well documented here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics)